# How to access fragments inside the rootview of an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose I have a fragment tag in my activity layout and some other tags. Now if I try to access this activities view from outside the activity I can get it by

```
View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Then I can its child views count by using method `rootView.getChildCount();`
Now if I loop over it and get all its childs as `rootView.getChildAt(i);`it returns a view. But what if I have a fragment as its child. A fragment is a subclass ob Object and not View. How do I get it from the rootview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that fragment by

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.static_fragment );
```

[Code Refrence](http://coreylatislaw.com/managing-static-and-dynamic-fragments/)

**But**, First There are 2 types of fragments

1. Static
2. Dynamic

we use them to get [Flexible UI](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui) that create a special UI for a tablet instead of the same UI as a phone screen. And you are talking about static fragments.

For example, A static fragment is `Fragment A`  now it is a list view that has onClickListner which adds `Fragment B` that need to be a dynamic fragment as it is changing dynamically not static as `Fragment A`. So Static fragment made to be static not to be accessed and changed

[image]

Comment: isn't there any way to get it through this:  rootView.getChildAt(i);

Comment: Actually, I don't know but you can try to get the child fragment and then cast it to fragment as `Fragment fragment = (Fragment) rootView.getChildAt(i)`, also I suggest you take a revision on how your app has to work. If you are new to Android Development then you need to continue your learning path because you are missing great important concepts

Comment: Thanks but actually its not my app. I have to make a module that runs with the main app and monitor it. So i have to think of every possible scenario that the other developer may have done. If it was for me, i would have simple used a viewpager or a framelayout instead of directly putting fragment tag.